# FIX protocol resend request procedure

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

I am trying to figure out what FIX resend (35=2) do , so I have my own FIX engine
to send the following message to FIX acceptor :

Notice : The following messages has 0x01 replaced by '|' already !!

```
Step1 :
logon : (8=FIX.4.2|9=86|35=A|34=12|49=YADTS|52=20160316-11:22:43.000|56=DS68AA|96=13575522|98=0|108=30|10=162|)

Step2:
receive : (8=FIX.4.2|9=00073|35=A|49=DS68AA|56=YADTS|34=9|52=20160316-03:22:48.744|108=30|98=0|10=200|)

logon looke like works !!!

Step3:
client resend request to accptor :
(8=FIX.4.2|9=72|35=2|34=13|49=YADTS|52=20160316-11:22:48.000|56=DS68AA|7=2|16=0|10=166|)

Step4:
client send heartbeat to accetor :
(8=FIX.4.2|9=62|35=0|34=14|49=YADTS|52=20160316-11:23:12.000|56=DS68AA|10=032|)

Step5:
accptor send to client :
(8=FIX.4.2|9=00072|35=2|49=DS68AA|56=YADTS|34=10|52=20160316-03:23:17.677|7=13|16=0|10=119|)

Step6:
acceptor send to client :
(8=FIX.4.2|9=00128|35=5|49=DS68AA|56=YADTS|34=11|52=20160316-03:23:47.676|58=A timeout occurred while waiting for a resend request response|10=232|)
```

What  I am bothered is , in Step5 , I am asking resend request with begin_seqno=2(7=2)  to the last seqno (16=0)  in Step3 .

But , Why in Step5 ,the accptor send resend request to client ?
Should not acceptor should resend message which seqno between 2 to the last ?!
I have no idea Why acceptor send the 35=2 message to client for ,
any commets are great appreciated !!

Comment: Maybe the server cannot respond to requests immediately and requests a resend once it was ready. I don't think it's invalid for the FIX server to send a resend request in response to yours.